# Unity: Grayscaling a single layer using two cameras also grayscales skybox?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've used the technique described here to grayscale selected objects (by placing them on a different layer): http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/using-multiple-unity-cameras-why-this-may-be-important/

However, I can't find a way to do this that doesn't also grayscale my skybox. It makes sense based on what I know -- the grayscaling is applied to the skybox-cleared first camera image before the color layers are rendered by the second camera.

To be clear, my setup is this:

camera 1:

- depth 0
- clear skybox
- culling mask: the layer with objects I want grayscaled

camera 2:

- depth 1
- don't clear
- culling mask: everything but the layers I want grayscaled

I've tried adding cameras both above and below these to try to render the skybox separately, but it makes sense based on my understanding of draw order that neither of these worked.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

PS - if it matters (don't think it does), this project is in Unity 2019.2 and I'm not using LWRP/HDRP (and would prefer not to, for now).

update: in response to the answer from @derHugo -- I've tried this, and it appears to yield all gray (tried it the first time and again following the answer, same results). These are screenshots of the settings suggested by derHugo, as I understand them; the main cam is 1st (with the audio listener), grayscale cam is 2nd:
[image: main camera]
[image: grayscale camera]

Comment: and what is this `Skybox` component and why is it still on the greyscale camera?

Comment: And what does `Greyscale` and the shader look like? Maybe there is something in there that works strange?

Comment: this is the standard assets one, but great question, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

The skybox is greyscaled in that example and your case since you put the greyscale effect on the same camera that also renderers the skybox (Clear Flags).

Since you do **not** want your skybox being greyscaled .. let the other not-grescaled camera render the skybox!

You only need these two Cameras:

The MainCamera:

- Clear Flags: **Skybox**
- Culling Mask: Everything exept the GreayscaleLayer
- Depth: **0** (anything smaller than GreyscaleCamera's Depth)

The GreyscaleCamera:

- Clear Flags: **Don't Clear** (Everything except the here rendered objects shall be "transparent")
- Culling Mask: Only GreyscaleLayer
- Depth: **1** (anything bigger than MainCamera's Depth)

> [Depth](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html):
>  The camera’s position in the draw order. Cameras with a larger value will be drawn on top of cameras with a smaller value.

meaning first the MainCamera will be rendered. Then the GreyscaleCamera "on top" of it. **But** since you used `Don't Clear` the depth-buffer will be intact and the objects on other layers (which already are rendered) may still appear in front of the greyscaled objects. And since you don't clear also the not greyscaled skybox will simply be rendered by the other camera and not changed later.

Of course you could further separate also the Skybox into a third Camera with `Culling Mask` nothing and set it to `Depth = -1`.

**In short: Just make sure your Skybox(Background) Camera has always the smallest `Depth` value.**

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I tried this, though, and it doesn't work -- at least the way I tried it. I updated the question with some screenshots of the settings you suggested. It may be me (I've never done this before!), but it seems that both in my case and in the article to which I linked, the higher depth camera applies its effects to the entire image. Any thoughts? Upvoted anyway but didn't accept yet :p

Comment: I did notice that I have skyboxes attached to both cameras, but removing one or the other didn't seem to make any difference. Not sure if relevant. Thank you again!